# Cron job with script sh is not executed but job is running in cron log

Tags: python, bash, cron

I try to set up a cron job to execute a python test program (rm a file from folder) but it doesn't work. 
I've tried different things : 
- Run programm with script sh
- Run action directly with command in crontab

When I launch test.sh from terminal, it works perfectly. When I launch  rm file directly in crontab command it works too BUT nothing happens when the script sh is launched from crontab...

This is my cron tab :

```
*/5 * * * * run_auto_resp_ads.sh
37 14 * * * test.sh
18 14 * * * rm ~/Rendu/test_cron/lol.py
```

This is test.sh content :

```
#!/bin/sh rm ~/Rendu/test_cron/lol2.py
```

When I check my cron logs, task are running :

```
Mar 15 14:21:01 AcerA17 CROND[14905]: (mjz) CMD (test.sh)
Mar 15 14:18:01 AcerA17 CROND[12944]: (mjz) CMD (rm ~/Rendu/test_cron/lol.py)
```

I've also checked files rights.

Any ideas please ? 
Thx a lot :)

Comment: Use absolute paths for everything in cron.

Comment: Or, better, put `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin` up at the top of your crontab, which will export that variable for all jobs it runs. Likewise, `HOME=/Users/magali` or such as appropriate.

Comment: BTW, `sh` and `bash` are two different shells. Using one in your title and the other in your tagging is confusing at best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cron doesn't inherit your environement.
`$HOME` is not set when you run your cron, thus the `~` is not interpoled.

You can set it like this:

```
HOME="/home/user"
18 14 * * * rm ~/Rendu/test_cron/lol.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Does test.sh consist of one single line? In that case, there you have part of the problem: the construct

```
#!/bin/sh
```

needs to stand alone on the first line. In your case "rm" will be sent as an argument to 'sh', which is not what you want.

Comment: No, rm is on a second line